# Jetpack compose - change bottom bar cutout color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomappbar, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

How to change the color of the cut out for the bottom bar?

I know it takes the color from `MaterialTheme.colors.background`, but I don't want to change the background color for all components, only for the bottom bar. (The white color in the cut out in the picture.)

[image]

I have tried different things, for example setting a new theme just for the bottom bar, but that doesn't work.

```
val bottomBarColors = MaterialTheme.colors.copy(background = Color.LightGray)
...

bottomBar = {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = bottomBarColors,
        typography = MaterialTheme.typography,
        shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes
    ) {
        BottomAppBar(
            cutoutShape = fabShape,
            content = {
                MyBottomNavigation(navController, bottomNavigationItems)
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: would you pleas share your codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can apply the `Modifier.background` to the `BottomAppBar`:

```
    bottomBar = {
        BottomAppBar(
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red),
            cutoutShape = fabShape) {

            BottomNavigation {
                /* .... */
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: how to make that color to be transparent?

Answer (score -1):

The solution was easier than I thought. Just add something below the bottom bar:

```
bottomBar = {
        Box {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize().background(color = Color.Blue))
            BottomAppBar(
                cutoutShape = fabShape,
                content = {
                    MyBottomNavigation(navController, bottomNavigationItems)
                })
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out Gabriele's answer. That is appropriate.

Comment: More official way of doing it